# Multidimensional Scaling Error

Tags: orange, multi-dimensional-scaling

I use Orange Program for Data mining.

In this platform, I use the function which is Multidimensional Scaling.(MDS)

My input file is 7224 * 150 matrix.

After running MDS function, an error is occurred.

When I run a small size file, MDS function runs well.

How can I solve this problem???

### This is an error message.

KernelException                               Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeCanvas\scheme\widgetsscheme.py", line 649, in process_signals_for_widget
    handler(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\Unsupervised\OWMDS.py", line 229, in cmatrix
    self.mds = orngMDS.MDS(matrix)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\utils__init__.py", line 214, in wrap_call
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\projection\mds.py", line 249, in **init**
    self.original_distances=Orange.misc.SymMatrix([m for m in self.distances])
KernelException: bad allocation

Answer (score 0):

The official Orange build for windows is 32-bit only, and is therefore limited to maximum of 4GB address space per process (this may be limited further to 2-3GB by the OS). The error you are seeing is a consequence of this, i.e. the process cannot allocate a contiguous memory buffer of sufficient size to store the matrix.

One possible solution is to install 64 bit Python, numpy/scipy stack from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: If I install 64 bit Python, Can I use Orange Program?( The official Oragne build for windows is 32-bit only. )